# Writing a file in j2me

Tags: java-me

My code is not working and not giving any exception:

```
OutputConnection con = (OutputConnection) Connector.open("file:///epsd/rescuer.txt", Connector.WRITE);
System.out.println("below con");
OutputStream out = con.openOutputStream();
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(out);
System.out.println("below ps");
ps.println(name+"!"+no+"!"+"!"+mtype+"!@!");    
System.out.println("below println");
ps.close();
con.close();
```

Control doesn't reach after `OutputConnection` line. Is this how to append data to a text file in J2ME?

Comment: I am not sure about it so please suggest some source code...

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to get the SDCard path and concat it with your file name

```
String memoryCardPath = System.getProperty("fileconn.dir.memorycard");
String filePath = memoryCardPath + "/rescuer.txt";
OutputConnection con = (OutputConnection) Connector.open(filePath, Connector.WRITE);
```

Comment: Is it work on J2ME Emulator or I have to try it on real device? it is throwing Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no ':' in URL.     Also, I want text file inside project(Application jar file) instead of inside SDCard card.

Comment: Your memoryCardPath variable might be without a "file://" prefix in it.